# Check if all checkboxes are checked, then add class to something

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I need to add a class to an element after all input checkboxes are checked, without having the need to click on a submit button. I'd much prefer not to get jQuery involved since this would be the only javascript element on the page. Here's what I have so far and it looks like it's adding the class after the first click on the checkbox, which is not what I want.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/brianyuen/pen/drQgBX)

**JS**

```
function showMe (box) {
  var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("selectPlant");
  for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++) {
    if(checkbox[i].checked){
      document.getElementById(box).classList.add('show');
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="reward" style="opacity:0">
  TADA!
</a>
<form action="" id="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectPlant" onclick="showMe('reward')">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectPlant" onclick="showMe('reward')">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectPlant" onclick="showMe('reward')">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectPlant" onclick="showMe('reward')">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#reward {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#reward.show {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the total number of checkboxes and increment a counter if a particular checkbox is ticked. If the numbers match, all checkboxes must be ticked.

```
function showMe (box) {
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("selectPlant");
    var counter=0;
    for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++) {
        if(checkbox[i].checked){
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter==checkbox.length)
        {
            document.getElementById(box).classList.add('show');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable for length check box and compare i with length.

```
 var length = checkbox.length;
      var check = 0;
      for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++) {
        if(checkbox[i].checked){

          check++;
        }
        if (check == length){
           document.getElementById(box).classList.add('show');
         }
      }
```

```js
function showMe (box) {
  var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("selectPlant");
  var length = checkbox.length;
  var check = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++) {
    if(checkbox[i].checked){
     
      check++;
    }
    if (check == length){
       document.getElementById(box).classList.add('show');
     }
  }
}
```

```css
#reward {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#reward.show {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="reward" style="opacity:0">
  TADA!
</a>
<form action="" id="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectPlant" onclick="showMe('reward')">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectPlant" onclick="showMe('reward')">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectPlant" onclick="showMe('reward')">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectPlant" onclick="showMe('reward')">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the normal behavior, this answer will default to true if no checkboxs are present

```
function showMe (box) {
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("selectPlant");
    var allChecked=true;
    for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++) {
        if(!checkbox[i].checked){
            allChecked = false;
        }
    }
    if(allChecked){
        document.getElementById(box).classList.add('show');
    }
}
```